# Can't get to move libgdx OrthographicCamera

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm having issues with the Camera class in libGDX, I just can't visually move it even though its position changes.

This is how I setup the camera:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(frustumWidth, frustumHeight);
```

This is how I change its position:

```
world.onUpdate(deltaTime, camera);
    renderer.render(world);
    camera.position.set(MathUtils.random(0, 800), MathUtils.random(0, 480), 0);
    //camera.position.set(
        //  world.dynamicObjects.get(GameWorld.MainPgID).pos.x * GameWorld.frustumToWorldRatio,
            //world.dynamicObjects.get(GameWorld.MainPgID).pos.y * GameWorld.frustumToWorldRatio, 0);
```

I submit the changes at the beginning of the .render function:

```
camera.update();
        batcher.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batcher.begin();
        polygonBatcher.begin();
```

As I've said the position does change, and yet of the many combinations I've tried none works.
Perhaps I misunderstood how the Camera works and I need to move the objects and not the camera? Seems to be stupid to me, after all it's called camera for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply the combined projection matrix on every batch/renderer you want it to affect.

But besides of that it seems to be fine. Try to debug it step by step. 
Setup a simple project with only `new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());` and some lines (ShapeRenderer) or sprites (SpriteBatch), set the projection matrix to `camera.combined`, change `camera.position` and `update()` the camera. That should do it.

Then when you change `camera.position` all the renderer with the camera's frustum should offset accordingly without changing the offsets of the sprites/geometry.

btw. the viewport is not 0 - 800, but rather -400 - 400 for x and respectively for y;

Comment: I had a similar issue: when I `camera.position.set(x,y,0)`, it rendered the wrong area for one frame. Your answer helped a lot.